# Will upgrading Windows 7 Home Premium to Ultimate replace my now corrupted system fonts folder?

Tags: windows-7

I'd ask this in an official Windows Stack Exchange place, but oddly, it doesn't exist.

I have Windows 7 Home Premium w/ corrupted system fonts and Windows/Fonts are read only and even after resetting permissions still can't delete fonts I accidentally stuck in there and shortcuts... I have an upgrade to Windows Ultimate I could run, but want to know if it's worth the hassle.

Thanks.

Comment: Someone call me out if I'm wrong, but wouldn't an `sfc /scannow` fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repair Windows first by doing an [inplace upgrade](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

- Mount your ISO or insert your DVD
- Run setup.exe from the DVD
- During setup select Upgrade, this repairs Windows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix, but Windows would not let me do the inplace upgrade (which is upsetting in itself because I paid $139 for this Ultimate DVD. It seems to have changed to 'please use Windows Anytime Upgrade'. So I did the full custom upgrade where it made the Windows.old folder and I've re-installed my programs. Was worth it because history has taught me, never touch the system fonts folder - it's too precarious. Thanks for your input.

Comment: ok, nice to hear you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

For the best result please try to restore your fonts folder with an ubuntu live cd